# GAE: OAuth 2.0 authorize url can't load in a Google Sites Gadget

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, oauth-2.0, google-sites, google-api-client

I have a Python application, executing in Google App Engine. The app uses Google Calendar API and api-client-library. My code, simplified, looks like this:

```
import webapp

oauth2_decorator = oauth2decorator_from_clientsecrets(
    CLIENT_SECRETS,
    scope=CALENDAR_SCOPE,
    message=MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE)

class MyRequestHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  @oauth2_decorator.oauth_aware
  def get(self):
    if oauth2_decorator.has_credentials():
      # do stuff
    else:
      self.response.out.write(oauth2_decorator.authorize_url())


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MyHandleRequest),
    (oauth2_decorator.callback_path, oauth2_decorator.callback_handler())
], debug=True)
```

So far, so good. First time user enters the app, it requests authorization to use the user's calendar. User provides authorization, and then the app works.

The problem arises when I integrate the app in a Google Site, using Google Sites Gadget. First time the user enters, the gadget shows blank content. If the user directly opens the content of that gadget (an appspot url), it works fine: authorize url is loaded and the app works.

Is there any known problem with appspot urls integrated inside Google Sites?

Many thanks in advance